# How to place a lever on a block using java in Minecraft Forge?

Tags: java, minecraft, minecraft-forge

In my minecraft mod i'm trying to write a piece of code that will place a block at given location and after placing the block place a lever on that block.

How can I accomplish this?

This is my code where I place my block on which the lever has to be placed.

```
BlockPos blockpos = new BlockPos(player.posX  + x*2 + xOffset,  
                                 player.posY /*+  player.getEyeHeight() + y*2 */+ counter, 
                                 player.posZ + z* 2);

world.setBlockState(blockpos, 
                    Blocks.cobblestone.getDefaultState());
```

So basically, I want to know the function that would place a lever on this block after placing it.

Or if there is some special type of blocks that has a lever on it by default, I would like to use it. I want to make an event happen when you click on the lever.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the blockpos object. You can get a new blockpos relative to this blockpos by using the following function:

```
//Assuming we are using your blockpos object
BlockPos leverPosition = blockpos.offset(EnumFacing.EAST);
```

And here you have your lever position to the east of the blockpos where you placed your cobblestone block.

Using whatever code you want to can discern which direction the player is facing

Then you do a simple setBlockState for the lever on that location and stuff should sort itself out :-)

From the comments:

```
 IBlockState leverState = Blocks
                         .lever
                         .getDefaultState()
                         .withProperty(BlockLever.FACING,                  
                                       BlockLever.EnumOrientation.SOUTH
                                       );
  world.setBlockState(startPosition.offset(EnumFacing.SOUTH), leverState);
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion and the lever appears but it's just to the east next to the block, which means that it's not placed on the block itself.. Is there a way to place the lever on the block to make it useable? I really appreciate your help, Thank you for your answer! :)

Comment: You need to set a specific blockstate. Open up the BlockLever definition to see which properties it accepts and set it to that state. Best way to learn is to always look at the source of the blocks. Probaly it'll need the opposite facing as the enumfacing you are using.

Comment: yes I actually tried: 
IBlockState leverState = Blocks.lever.getDefaultState().withProperty(BlockLever.FACING, BlockLever.EnumOrientation.SOUTH); 
     world.setBlockState(startPosition.offset(EnumFacing.SOUTH), leverState);
 And it worked! Thank you very much Michael :)

Comment: Hey, do you have some idea about how to add event handling for when the player right-clicks on this lever? I want to do it but I have never tried event handling before. I found some tutorials that use other events but I couldn't find the one I want.

Comment: Don't place cobble,  but your own block(that can look like cobble)  and use the powered by redstone method to do your thing

Comment: Okey, I added my own Block which I have created some time ago, it's called BlockBlack. I checked the class Block to find the powered by redstone method but I can't find it. where is it?

Comment: These questions you can better post as seperate questions. Each question it's own topic. for your reference read: http://www.minecraftforge.net/forum/index.php?topic=31672.0

Comment: Yes you're right :) I posted another question for this. Thank you very much for your help! I really appreciate it, guided me a lot!